# Emacs / Doom emacs taking a lot of memory

Tags: spacemacs, doom, performance

I'm using Doom Emacs, which is taking a lot of Memory if my browser is opened with 10 tabs.
What can I do to reduce amount of memory being used, without sacrificing the packages?

[image: ram]

My config.el is as

```
(add-to-list 'default-frame-alist
             '(ns-transparent-titlebar . t))


(setq user-full-name ""
      user-mail-address "")

(setq doom-theme 'doom-tomorrow-night)
(setq org-directory "~/org/")

(setq display-line-numbers-type t)


(setq ring-bell-function 1)

(require 'company-dict)
(setq company-dict-dir (concat user-emacs-directory "dict/"))

(add-to-list 'company-backends 'company-dict)

(define-key evil-insert-state-map (kbd "C-x C-k") 'company-dict)

(add-to-list 'default-frame-alist '(inhibit-double-buffering . t))
(setq fancy-splash-image (concat doom-private-dir "logo3.png"))
(remove-hook '+doom-dashboard-functions #'doom-dashboard-widget-shortmenu)
(remove-hook '+doom-dashboard-functions #'doom-dashboard-widget-footer)



(use-package! beacon)
(beacon-mode 1)
(setq beacon-color "red")
;; (setq beacon-blink-duration 0.1)
(setq beacon-blink-when-window-scrolls 1)
(setq beacon-blink-when-point-moves-vertically 1)



(defface custom-line-highlight '((t
                                    (:foreground "#61dafb" :extend t)
                                    )) "")
(add-hook
 'treemacs-mode-hook
 (defun channge-hl-line-mode ()
   (setq-local hl-line-face 'custom-line-highlight)
   (overlay-put hl-line-overlay 'face hl-line-face)
   (treemacs--setup-icon-background-colors)))


(after! treemacs
  (setq evil-treemacs-state-cursor 1
        treemacs-show-cursor 1
        ))

(functionp 'json-serialize)
(setq gc-cons-threshold 100000000)
(setq read-process-output-max (* 1024 1024)) ;; 1mb
;; (setq lsp-idle-delay 0.500)
(setq byte-compile-warnings '(cl-functions))




;; Fonts

(setq doom-font (font-spec :family "JetBrainsMono" :size 12 :weight 'light)
      doom-variable-pitch-font (font-spec :family "Noto Serif" :size 13)
      ivy-posframe-font (font-spec :family "JetBrainsMono" :size 15))

(after! doom-themes
  (setq doom-themes-enable-bold t
        doom-themes-enable-italic t))
(custom-set-faces!
  '(font-lock-comment-face :slant italic)
  '(font-lock-keyword-face :slant italic))
```

my packages.el as

```
(package! prettier-js)
```

my init.el as

```
(doom! :input
       ;;chinese
       ;;japanese
       ;;layout            ; auie,ctsrnm is the superior home row

       :completion
       company           ; the ultimate code completion backend
       ;;helm              ; the *other* search engine for love and life
       ;;ido               ; the other *other* search engine...
       ;;ivy               ; a search engine for love and life
       vertico           ; the search engine of the future

       :ui
       ;; deft              ; notational velocity for Emacs
       doom              ; what makes DOOM look the way it does
       doom-dashboard    ; a nifty splash screen for Emacs
       ;; doom-quit         ; DOOM quit-message prompts when you quit Emacs
       ;;(emoji +unicode)  ; 
       hl-todo           ; highlight TODO/FIXME/NOTE/DEPRECATED/HACK/REVIEW
       ;;hydra
       indent-guides     ; highlighted indent columns
       ;;ligatures         ; ligatures and symbols to make your code pretty again
       minimap           ; show a map of the code on the side
       (modeline +light)          ; snazzy, Atom-inspired modeline, plus API
       ;;nav-flash         ; blink cursor line after big motions
       ;;neotree           ; a project drawer, like NERDTree for vim
       ophints           ; highlight the region an operation acts on
       (popup +defaults)   ; tame sudden yet inevitable temporary windows
       tabs              ; a tab bar for Emacs
       treemacs          ; a project drawer, like neotree but cooler
       ;;unicode           ; extended unicode support for various languages
       vc-gutter         ; vcs diff in the fringe
       vi-tilde-fringe   ; fringe tildes to mark beyond EOB
       window-select     ; visually switch windows
       workspaces        ; tab emulation, persistence & separate workspaces
       zen               ; distraction-free coding or writing

       :editor
       (evil +everywhere); come to the dark side, we have cookies
       file-templates    ; auto-snippets for empty files
       fold              ; (nigh) universal code folding
       ;;(format +onsave)  ; automated prettiness
       ;;god               ; run Emacs commands without modifier keys
       ;;lispy             ; vim for lisp, for people who don't like vim
       multiple-cursors  ; editing in many places at once
       ;;objed             ; text object editing for the innocent
       ;;parinfer          ; turn lisp into python, sort of
       rotate-text       ; cycle region at point between text candidates
       snippets          ; my elves. They type so I don't have to
       ;;word-wrap         ; soft wrapping with language-aware indent

       :emacs
       (dired +ranger +icons)             ; making dired pretty [functional]
       electric          ; smarter, keyword-based electric-indent
       ibuffer         ; interactive buffer management
       undo              ; persistent, smarter undo for your inevitable mistakes
       vc                ; version-control and Emacs, sitting in a tree

       :term
       ;;eshell            ; the elisp shell that works everywhere
       ;;shell             ; simple shell REPL for Emacs
       ;;term              ; basic terminal emulator for Emacs
       vterm             ; the best terminal emulation in Emacs

       :checkers
       syntax              ; tasing you for every semicolon you forget
       ;;(spell +flyspell) ; tasing you for misspelling mispelling
       ;;grammar           ; tasing grammar mistake every you make

       :tools
       ;;ansible
       ;;debugger          ; FIXME stepping through code, to help you add bugs
       ;;direnv
       ;;docker
       ;;editorconfig      ; let someone else argue about tabs vs spaces
       ;;ein               ; tame Jupyter notebooks with emacs
       (eval +overlay)     ; run code, run (also, repls)
       ;;gist              ; interacting with github gists
       lookup              ; navigate your code and its documentation
       lsp               ; M-x vscode
       magit             ; a git porcelain for Emacs
       ;;make              ; run make tasks from Emacs
       pass              ; password manager for nerds
       ;;pdf               ; pdf enhancements
       ;;prodigy           ; FIXME managing external services & code builders
       ;;rgb               ; creating color strings
       ;;taskrunner        ; taskrunner for all your projects
       terraform         ; infrastructure as code
       ;;tmux              ; an API for interacting with tmux
       ;;upload            ; map local to remote projects via ssh/ftp

       :os
       (:if IS-MAC macos)  ; improve compatibility with macOS
       ;;tty               ; improve the terminal Emacs experience

       :lang
       ;;agda              ; types of types of types of types...
       ;;beancount         ; mind the GAAP
       (cc +lsp)                ; C > C++ == 1
       ;;clojure           ; java with a lisp
       ;;common-lisp       ; if you've seen one lisp, you've seen them all
       ;;coq               ; proofs-as-programs
       ;;crystal           ; ruby at the speed of c
       ;;csharp            ; unity, .NET, and mono shenanigans
       ;;data              ; config/data formats
       ;;(dart +flutter)   ; paint ui and not much else
       ;;dhall
       ;;elixir            ; erlang done right
       ;;elm               ; care for a cup of TEA?
       emacs-lisp        ; drown in parentheses
       ;;erlang            ; an elegant language for a more civilized age
       ;;ess               ; emacs speaks statistics
       ;;factor
       ;;faust             ; dsp, but you get to keep your soul
       ;;fsharp            ; ML stands for Microsoft's Language
       ;;fstar             ; (dependent) types and (monadic) effects and Z3
       ;;gdscript          ; the language you waited for
       (go +lsp)         ; the hipster dialect
       ;;(haskell +lsp)    ; a language that's lazier than I am
       ;;hy                ; readability of scheme w/ speed of python
       ;;idris             ; a language you can depend on
       json              ; At least it ain't XML
       (java +meghanada) ; the poster child for carpal tunnel syndrome
       (javascript +lsp)        ; all(hope(abandon(ye(who(enter(here))))))
       ;; julia             ; a better, faster MATLAB
       ;;kotlin            ; a better, slicker Java(Script)
       ;;latex             ; writing papers in Emacs has never been so fun
       ;;lean              ; for folks with too much to prove
       ;;ledger            ; be audit you can be
       ;;lua               ; one-based indices? one-based indices
       markdown          ; writing docs for people to ignore
       ;;nim               ; python + lisp at the speed of c
       ;;nix               ; I hereby declare "nix geht mehr!"
       ;;ocaml             ; an objective camel
       (org +brain +pomodoro +pretty)               ; organize your plain life in plain text
       php               ; perl's insecure younger brother
       ;;plantuml          ; diagrams for confusing people more
       ;;purescript        ; javascript, but functional
       (python +pyright)            ; beautiful is better than ugly
       ;;qt                ; the 'cutest' gui framework ever
       ;;racket            ; a DSL for DSLs
       ;;raku              ; the artist formerly known as perl6
       ;; rest              ; Emacs as a REST client
       ;;rst               ; ReST in peace
       ;;(ruby +rails)     ; 1.step {|i| p "Ruby is #{i.even? ? 'love' : 'life'}"}
       (rust +lsp)              ; Fe2O3.unwrap().unwrap().unwrap().unwrap()
       ;;scala             ; java, but good
       ;;(scheme +guile)   ; a fully conniving family of lisps
       sh                ; she sells {ba,z,fi}sh shells on the C xor
       ;;sml
       ;;solidity          ; do you need a blockchain? No.
       ;;swift             ; who asked for emoji variables?
       ;;terra             ; Earth and Moon in alignment for performance.
       web               ; the tubes
       ;;yaml              ; JSON, but readable
       ;;zig               ; C, but simpler

       :email
       ;;(mu4e +org +gmail)
       ;;notmuch
       ;;(wanderlust +gmail)

       :app
       ;;calendar
       ;;emms
       ;;everywhere        ; *leave* Emacs!? You must be joking
       ;;irc               ; how neckbeards socialize
       ;;(rss +org)        ; emacs as an RSS reader
       ;;twitter           ; twitter client https://twitter.com/vnought

       :config
       ;;literate
       (default +bindings +smartparens))
```

I've not installed much packages but still taking a lot of ram :(

Comment: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/tags/elisp/info

Comment: What packages? Please provide a recipe to reproduce and explain your problem.

Comment: Why do you believe that Emacs using 240.8 MB of RAM / memory is taking up too much of your system memory?  That looks pretty low to me assuming your machine was built in the last 10 years, that is ...  Is there something about performance when using Emacs that is causing you concern?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possibly a duplicate.

[Find out module slowing down emacs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17318615/find-out-module-slowing-down-emacs)

This may be what you're looking for.

[Emacs Lisp Profiler](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/EmacsLispProfiler)